# Livewire child component freezes parent component once refreshed

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a simple `ExpenseShow` component that has a child `ExpenseForm` component.
On `ExpenseShow` I have a simple update button:

```
<x-cards. Button 
    wire:click"$emitTo('expenses. Expense-form', 'editExpense', {{$expense->id}})"
>
   Edit Expense
</x-cards. Button>
...
@livewire('expenses.expense-new-form')
```

The click of the button emits the `editExpense` event, which opens a modal and the expense is Updated as expected. Then I emit back to `$this->emitTo('expenses.expense-show', 'refreshComponent');` from the child component (update method on `ExpenseForm') and it freezes my page (parent component after modal goes away and database is updated.) for a couple of seconds.

However, when I use `wire.poll` on the `ExpenseShow` component in the blade everything updates fine with no delay. I just think it's wasteful for this scenario. I don't need the server running requests every 2 seconds, that's why I think `refreshComponent` is more applicable here. Any ideas? My `ExpenseForm` has a few dropdowns with hundreds of entries each but `wire:poll` has no delay and it does it nonstop.

Thanks for any input. Patryk.

Edit:
There was an answer here that made sense. It looks like he deleted his answer. I meant to mark it as Answered when I implemented one of the options. I hope that nice user showa it again. In a nutshell, he suggested I bind my parent and child components via `wire: model` or that I use `livewire: loading` or something about `livewire: on` to replace my `on: click` and `emit`... can anyone fill in the gaps? Not sure why their answer was deleted...

Comment: `wire:poll` is likely smashing it, causing your delay, perhaps a setTimeout is appropriate somewhere to prevent that, or only poll every 30 seconds or something

Comment: thanks, I wasn't clear. I don't have wire:poll on the `ExpenseShow` component when I try the `$refresh` listener and vice versa. `wire:poll` does the job (every 2 seconds), `$refresh` only when called does not.

Comment: Your `wire:click` in your button has syntax errors, is that just a typo in your question? Should be `wire:click="$emitTo('expenses.expense-form', 'editExpense', {{$expense->id}})"`

Comment: Unfortunately just SO auto code correct that emit works fine.

Comment: --updated question with details from a deleted answer. Need help to track it down please! "hmm, there was an answer here that made sense. It looks like he deleted his answer. I meant to mark it as Answered when I implemented one of the options. I hope that nice users show it again. In a nutshell, he suggested I bind my parent and child components via `wire: model` or that I use `livewire: loading` or something about `livewire:on` to replace my `on: click` and `emit`... can anyone fill in the gaps? Not sure why their answer was deleted..."

Comment: Wow. When I wrote this post both Chrome and Edge browsers experienced both issues. Since then, Chrome has been updated and I was able to achieve my desired result per livewire docs ( refresh Component ), shortly after it looks like Microsoft Edge is also working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. When I wrote this post both Chrome and Edge browsers experienced both issues. Since then, Chrome has been updated and I was able to achieve my desired result per livewire docs ( refresh Component ), shortly after it looks like Microsoft Edge is also working!